# Raspberry Pi Jessie Wi-Fi doesn't work with multiple IPs on same network

Tags: networking, wifi, ip, raspbian

I would like to use two different static IP addresses for the same network with the same Wi-Fi dongle. I read in different forums that it's better to use `/etc/network/interfaces` instead of `dhcpcd.conf` for that purpose.
So I changed the `/etc/network/interfaces` that way:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.60
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.10
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
auto wlan0:0
allow-hotplug wlan0:0
iface wlan0:0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.61
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The issue now is that for the most of the time I can't ping any member of the network. During the first 10 seconds, everything works fine and then I mostly don't get any connection.

`ifconfig` shows the following:

```
lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX packets:1237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1 
          RX bytes:100748 (98.3 KiB)  TX bytes:100748 (98.3 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse b8:27:eb:a2:4b:72  
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.60  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::ba27:ebff:fea2:4b72/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX packets:15498 errors:0 dropped:10634 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5446 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX bytes:5910381 (5.6 MiB)  TX bytes:722284 (705.3 KiB)

wlan0:0   Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse b8:27:eb:a2:4b:72  
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.61  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
```

and route -ne has the following output:

```
 Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags   MSS Fenster irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.10    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

I also stoped dhcpcd, the IPs aren't in the dhcp IP pool of the router and with one static IP everything works fine 
Does anyone have any clue what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a multiple IP address to your `wlan0` interface , edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.60/24
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.10
     wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.61/24
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Save your file then reboot.

Type the following command:

```
sudo ip a
```

Sample output:

```
inet 192.168.0.60/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
inet 192.168.0.61/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global secondary wlan0
```

To test it you can `ssh` from `192.168.0.60` or `192.168.0.61`

You can use the `ip` command to set up a temporary IPs to your network interface:

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.60/24 dev wlan0
sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.61/24 dev wlan0
```