# Adding Multiple IPs to One Network Interface

Tags: networking

I've read several articles and tried various methods and I'm pulling my hair out... I know the answer is punching me in the nose but I just cant seem to see it.

I have 2 network ports on my server (Debian LAMP):
eno1
eno2

I have a block of 5 IP addresses and I'm trying to assign the extra IPs to eno2 (or eno1, I don't care).

I have read the debian wiki and tried[image: Network Config network/interfaces]!

I added netmask field however dont believe it has to be there per debian wiki.

I got all IPs to ping successfully the other night with listing as(no alias #):
Iface eno2 inet static
Address ***.***.***.*01

Iface eno2 inet static
Address ***.***.***.*02

Etc.. But then the following morning ALL interfaces were down and had to do a hard reboot which brought eno1 back online (though the "aliases" did not work after that, only the first IP set for the interface was reachable on both eno1 and eno2)

I've also tried using aliases:
iface eno2:1 inet static
address ***.***.***.***

I am using tabs properly (I believe) for the address field as i read in a similar article that spaces wont work properly on network config.

What am I doing wrong? Or may be I'm misunderstanding an answer in a relevant article.

I appreciate any information provided. If all else fails I will just use a single ip for eno1 and another single ip for eno2. I'm scared to do any changes under /dev/network (if I recall correctly) because I'll cost myself another 1hour drive to my server.

Guessing in the wind: Interface aliases MAC addresses are posing an issue? May be make each interface alias with their own MAC? If so, what is a good method for making MAC addresses?

Final piece I'll add: I thought I had this configured correctly because if I run ifdown eno2 && ifup eno2 it would bring network interface back online. Some variations of the file would fail when running that command... so I feel like in all over the answer but again I feel I'm missing a very small detail.

Debian 9 w/ Apache

Comment: I know this is very close to a duplicate as I've read just about every other article out there from and not from SE. I'm still getting familiar with proper posting, so if you're going to downvote please post a link or just delete my post entirely and I'll have given up

Comment: Wow - Perfect. All I was missing was "allow-hotplug eno2"

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

So as GAD3R posted [Raspberry Pi Jessie Wi-Fi doesn't work with multiple IPs on same network](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403970/raspberry-pi-jessie-wi-fi-doesnt-work-with-multiple-ips-on-same-network) I discovered all I was missing was "allow-hotplug".
A little confusing because the debian wiki: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration appeared to be excluding that line for alias interfaces.

In any event, my configuration is working now with the following configuration:

```
# The secondary network interface - port 2
allow-hotplug eno2  
iface eno2 inet static  
    address 24.173.000.83  
    netmask 255.255.255.000  
    gateway 24.173.000.81  
    dns-nameservers 209.18.00.00  
    dns-nameservers 209.18.00.00 

# Secondary Network Interface Aliases
allow-hotplug eno2  
iface eno2 inet static  
    address 24.173.000.84  
    netmask 255.255.255.000

allow-hotplug eno2  
iface eno2 inet static  
    address 24.173.000.85  
    netmask 255.255.255.0

allow-hotplug eno2  
iface eno2 inet static  
    address 24.173.000.86  
    netmask 255.255.255.000
```

Comment: You can have multiple stanzas of one interface in /etc/network/interfaces and one 'allow-hotplug eno2' will do for all of them. In your initial configuration you used 'eno2:1', 'eno2:2', etc., which will then be considered as a different interface and therefore fell out of the allow-hotplug for interface eno2.

Comment: I tried allow-hotplug eno2 with multiple stanzas of iface eno2 inet static (no alias) however functionality seemed intermittent. Ideally I'd like to use the aliases (eno2:1 eno2:2 eno2:3) as recommended by the wiki vs eno2 eno2 eno2 stanzas. I'll play around with the settings some more and get rid of the netmask on and add alias #s(eno2:#)  I really appreciate the help - I knew it was something "simple" but simple isnt always "simple".. hah! I'm content now that all my IPs are utilized. Thanks for the additional info!

Comment: I could be walking of thin ice, but I think the èno2:1` notation is outdated, and I know it only out of the old `ifconfig` days. Could that wiki be a bit outdated?